# Is there a good sample MVC application using NCommon?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nhibernate, ncommon

My searches are not surfacing anything. Does anyone know of a good sample MVC application that uses the NCommon framework? We are looking for a good framework that will support either EF 4 or NHibernate 3. NCommon appears to fit the bill in that regard, but the project is sorely lacking any good code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on NCommon over a year ago.  I was not able to get the project owner to address a very simple pull request.  In fact it's [still open](https://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon/pulls).  It's not really very hard to [roll your own UnitOfWork implementation](http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx).  Domain events are even easier to roll your own.

If you really want to take a dependency on a stack, you might look at [Sharp Arcihtecture](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture) instead.

Comment: Thanks for that. The more I look at NCommon, the less I like it.